# How can I redirect using hook_init()?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

When the requested page is /user/login, users should be redirected to /mylogin.

I know this is possible with `hook_init()` or `hook_boot()`. Can someone explain how this can be achieved, exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function mymodule_init() {
  global $base_url;
  if (user_is_anonymous() && arg(0) == 'user') {
    drupal_goto($base_url . 'mylogin');
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `drupal_goto()` in `hook_init()` often leads to issues. I'd rather not do it.