# Redirect for specific path links

Tags: 7, redirection

I have to make redirect for links:
http://example.com/file/file1.pdf
http://example.com/file/file2.pdf
...
to links:
http://example.com/sites/default/files/file1.pdf
http://example.com/sites/default/files/file2.pdf
...
I've tried .htaccess changing, but fail. (it's too Voodoo for me)
[Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) project has no such function (afaik).
I don't know what hook can I use in my module for such redirect.

How can I make such redirect?

**UPDATE:**

I've created simple .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ sites/default/files/$1 [L]
```

And it works.

But when I insert in original Drupal .htaccess
line `RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ sites/default/files/$1 [L]` after `RewriteEngine on`
- there is no successful redirect.

Why?

**SOLUTION:**

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ sites/default/files/$1 [L, R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have learned the Redirect module is really for *page-specific* redirects (this single URL redirects to that URL), not *patterns*, as your case seems to require. For this a server-side redirect is really the way to go. Not only is it a standard solution to this kind of problem, but it can happen independent of Drupal, so there is no need to bootstrap Drupal just to process the redirect.

I think the specifics of setting-up a server-side redirect a a bit are a bit beyond the scope of this space (as it's not a Drupal-specific concept), but there are **lots** of resources out there on the topic, and I think you'll find that it's not too hard. You mentioned that it feels like "Voodo", but I think it will prove far more straightforward than a module-based solution implemented in php. Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273608/redirect-from-one-directory-to-another-with-mod-rewrite) stackexchange post that might be relevant to your case.

All that said, because your question does ask for a moudle-specific way to do it, here are some notes on that too. This is much less ideal, as noted above, but it's worth referencing. For this I think you would want to trigger a [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) inside of [hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7). A very simple-case example of this pattern can be referenced in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34784/how-to-redirect-the-user-using-hook-init), and interpolated for your example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function mymodule_init() {
  $path = current_path();
  // preg_match() could also work instead of drupal_match_path()
  if (drupal_match_path($path, 'file/*')) {
    drupal_goto('sites/default/' . $path);
  }
}
```

I suppose there may be real use cases for this kind of module-based approach, but as I noted above, I really don't think your case is one of them. You would probably be best-served with a service-side redirect (in Apache/.htaccess).

Comment: I've updated the question. I've tried .htaccess woodoo again, but without success. Where can be problem?

Comment: I think you might need a flag at the end to signify a redirect ([R]). See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). You may also need to signify the slash (/) in your source pattern, but I'm not positive on that... `RewriteRule ^/file/(.*)$ sites/default/files/$1 [L,R=301]`. Anyway, these specifics might be better suited for http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting from one url to another You can try

https://www.drupal.org/project/path_redirect module to redirect from one URl to another

This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another path or an external URL, using any HTTP redirect status.

## D7CX: I pledge that Path redirect will have a full Drupal 7 release on the day that Drupal 7 is released. Note that the project has moved to http://drupal.org/project/redirect for Drupal 7.

Comment: Isn't Path Redirect just the D6 version of Redirect?

Comment: yes you are right but if you can see the project page that specified in redirect module is also workable i ll update the answer :)